# Style triggering of Combobox WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm new bee to WPF. I've this problem with combobox.

When Combobox is rendered first time and has nothing to display, the border of combobox must set to red but unfortunately its not doing.

Please find the code snippet

```
<Style x:Key="requiredFieldValidationStyleComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource FaultyBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.ToolTip" Value="Input value is mandatory" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: What is SelectedItem binded object? It has Content property at all?

Comment: I'm sure you've already checked this but have you put the style on the combo box? <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource requiredFieldValidationStyleComboBox}"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what object you bind to selectedItem.
But I have a feeling you're going to ask if the SelectedItem itself equal to null,
Then the code should look like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ComboBox.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource FaultyBorderBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="ComboBox.ToolTip" Value="Input value is mandatory" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

"Content" is unnecessary.

This is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I found your style to work perfectly once I added it to a combo box, make sure the combo box actually has it's style property set or remove the x:Key property if you want it to apply to all combo boxes.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="requiredFieldValidationStyleComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.ToolTip" Value="Input value is mandatory" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,401,279">
        <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource requiredFieldValidationStyleComboBox}" Margin="46,66,-46,-66"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Nothing selected]

[image: Selected]